# trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt not work in stability

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to make swipe-able table view cell for iOS 11 and above and trying to use the **trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt** but it works on iPad and doesn't work on iPhone. 
 It is not called in iPhone. 
Surprisingly if I try to swipe the cell more then 10 or 20 times it sometimes works for once.

Here is my controller's table view extension

```
import UIKit

extension CustomViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func initTableView() {
        tableView.register(cell: SingleLineListItemViewCell.self)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 64
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

        tableView.backgroundColor = .green
        tableView.isEditing = false
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let model = SingleLineListItemViewModel(title: "coko")

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SingleLineListItemViewCell.reuseIdentifier) as? SingleLineListItemViewCell
        cell?.model = model
        cell?.isFirst = indexPath.row == 0
        cell?.isLast = indexPath.row == 2
        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return  100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 64.0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        print("didSelectRowAt....")
        router?.routeToTransfer()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    @available(iOS 11.0, *)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        return nil
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Action here
        // In case of delete, you can simply do:
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            //Remove item at relative position from datasource array
            //Reload tableview at the respective indexpath
        }
    }

    @available(iOS 11.0, *)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { _, _, _ in
            //YOUR_CODE_HERE
        }
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red
        let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
        configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
        return configuration
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only obvious thing wrong with this is that you're not calling the completion handler.  According to the API documentation it is necessary to call the completion handler to indicate whether the operation was successful. What it actually does I have no idea...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { _, _, completionHandler in
       //YOUR_CODE_HERE
       completionHandler(true)
     }
     deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red
     let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
     configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
     return configuration
}
```

If this doesn't make any difference, do you have any other gesture recognisers that could be conflicting with the swipe action?

Comment: Yes, you are right, after deleting the gesture recognizer it worked, thank you

Comment: @ondermerol if this solved your problem it would be good if you could accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> String? {
    return "Delete"
}

// this method handles row deletion
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {

        // remove the item from the data model

        // delete the table view row
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Not used in our example, but if you were adding a new row, this is where you would do it.
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let action = UIContextualAction(
        style: .normal,
        title: "Delete",
        handler: { (action, view, completion) in
            //do what you want here
            completion(true)
    })

    action.backgroundColor = .red
    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
    configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return configuration
    }
```

Comment: This should work, but this delegate method has been deprecated in iOS13 in favour of the one used by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is are actions defined as well (point 1 and 2);

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "") { _, _, completionHandler in

        // 1. remove object from your array
        scannedItems.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        // 2. reload the table, otherwise you get an index out of bounds crash
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        completionHandler(true)
    }
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
    deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "trash")
    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
    configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = true
    return configuration
}
```